# Gxt: gridview with row header

Tags: gridview, header, row, gxt

I'm very new to GXT and webapp.

I have created a class that extends GridView, I can configure the number of columns, the columns header and display some rows, it works.

I would like to add a header for each rows, this header should have the same look and feel as the column header (I would like to get a table similar to an Excel sheet).

I cannot find any information about this, Is there're a way to add a row header? Is there a tutorial or some examples?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If I get you clear - you need something like this https://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:groupinggrid
And then - you'll need to customize grouping row